# gsap mouse trailing on v3

Tags: javascript, gsap

I'm trying to get the effect shown in [this pen](https://codepen.io/osublake/pen/mEpado) using gsap v3, but can't get it to work. 
The provided pen is in older version of gsap, I tried converting it as shown below:

```
            const createLine = (leader, i) => {
            let line = document.createElementNS(svgns, 'line');
            line.setAttribute('data-svg-origin', '0 0');
            rootSvg.appendChild(line);

            gsap.set(line, { x: -15, y: -15, alpha: (5 - i) / 5 });

            let posX = gsap.getProperty(line, 'x');
            let posY = gsap.getProperty(line, 'y');

            gsap.to(line, 1000, {
                x: '+=1',
                y: '+=1',
                repeat: -1,
                modifiers: {
                    x: () => {
                        let x = posX + (leader.x - posX) * ease;
                        line.setAttribute('x2', leader.x - x);
                        return x;
                    },
                    y: () => {
                        let y = posY + (leader.y - posY) * ease;
                        line.setAttribute('y2', leader.y - y);
                        return y;
                    }
                }
            });

            return { x: posX, y: posY };
        };
```

But this produces very buggy output. How can I make this work using gsap v3.

Comment: You should include enough code to reproduce the "buggy output" in the question itself. You should also include a more clear description of what "buggy output" means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using static values inside of the modifier functions whereas the original is pulling values every update from the objects. Use `gsap.getProperty()` *inside* of the modifiers functions for *both* the `line` and the `leader` and it will behave like you want it to: [**Demo**](https://codepen.io/GreenSock/pen/wvBjdWP?editors=0010)